# Isolating JAX-RS redundancies causing NoSuchMethodError error

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

Conventional wisdom seems to indicate that this error I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map
```

Is the result of a collision between JAX-RS versions, however, I’m at a loss as to how to systematically locate where the collision might be happening.  Although this problem seemingly popped up spontaneously after having gone a year or so since compiling/running the app, I must have faced something similar in the past because what I understand to be attempted invocations are already excluded (I think) in my pom.xml.  I’m obviously missing something - but I’m falling short in my debug attempts.  I played with mvn tree and got this:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.ws.rs
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------< edu.mayo.ima.directory:MDS-Committee-WS >---------------
[INFO] Building MDS-Committee-WS 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ MDS-Committee-WS ---
[INFO] edu.mayo.ima.directory:MDS-Committee-WS:war:1.0.0
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.1)
[INFO] \- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
```

I’m confused because several of the items above listed with “compile” I would have thought were excluded in my pom.xml (below), e.g.,

javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:compile
javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile

So my overall objective is the exclude what redundancy is causing the problem, but I need help/suggestions on isolating the culprits.  If anyone has the time and inclination, I'd like to hear about recommended systematic ways/tools for approaching something like this.  In any case, thanks in advance for anything you can offer.  Here's my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.mayo.ima.directory</groupId>
  <artifactId>MDS-Committee-WS</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>MDS-Committee-WS</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <id>ComOpSys</id>
  <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mclm/_packaging/ComOpSys/maven/v1</url>
  <!--<releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots> -->
</repository>
</distributionManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.26</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.4</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency> -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sybase.jdbc4</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>ComOpSys</id>
  <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mclm/_packaging/ComOpSys/maven/v1</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>mclm@Local</id>
  <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mclm/_packaging/mclm%40Local/maven/v1</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    </properties>
  <build>
    <!-- <finalName>MDS-Committee-WS</finalName> -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
      <!-- <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> -->
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>
              src/main/webapp
            </directory>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sebastian-daschner</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.14</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>analyze-jaxrs</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <backend>swagger</backend>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin> -->
    </plugins>
      <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</sourceDirectory>
      <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Remove `jsr311-api` and use [this swagger dependency](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  Pulling my hair out trying to find old Jersey dependencies, but with no luck. Nothing explicit, at least in my tree:

Comment: Did you remove the old swagger dependency and did you clean the project? There's nothing else that could cause this error exact error unless you are running on glassfish server.

Comment: I failed to do the clean - did that, re-identified the artifacts and it took worked.  Appreciate you time and feedback, Paul!